# How to Alter Column Data Type Snowflake Error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working with a table in Snowflake that has the field "YEAR" as Varchar(4) for its data type. I am trying to change the field to an integer so I can do some addition to it.

```
ALTER TABLE A
ALTER COLUMN YEAR INTEGER;
```

I keep getting the error "cannot change column YEAR from type VARCHAR(4) to NUMBER(38,0)". Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Does the column contain data? If it does then you probably can't change the datatype. Assuming the data it contains can be converted to integers (i.e. it doesn't contain a value such as 'AAAA') then do the following:

1. Add a new column with INTEGER datatype
2. Update the new column with values from the existing column - cast to integers
3. Drop the existing column (having checked that the new column holds the correct values, obviously!)
4. Rename the new column to the old column name